# how to pass table row values to next page in input text field after clicking submit button

Tags: php, html

i want $row['Requirement_Number'],$row['Req_Date'],$row['Requirement_Name'] values is displayed in input field in next page how to get this value to next page please help me

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
 <tr>

                    <td><?php echo $row['Requirement_Number'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Req_Date'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Requirement_Name'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Location'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Required_Visa_Status'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Rate'];?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row['REQ_DESCRIPTION'];?></td>
                <td><a href="data.php"><input type="submit" name="Requirement_Number" Value=""></a></td>
                   </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: I presume the row details are obtained from your database? If so instead of using $_GET maybe just send the ID of that row to the next page in using $_GET to obtain the ID and then run a SQL to echo all the required details? I am not a fan on using array in your URL as someone changes just a ID number and may be able to see info they not supposed to see

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><a href="data.php?requirement_number=<?php echo $row['Requirement_Number'];?>"><input type="submit" name="Requirement_Number" Value=""></a></td>
```

on another page get this value in `$_GET` variable
suppose: 
    `<?php $requirementNumber = (isset($_GET['requirement_number']) ?  $_GET['requirement_number'] : ''; ?>`

add this variable to your input field
`<input type = 'text' value = '<?php echo $requirementNumber; ?>'>`

Comment: thanks its working but i want req_date and Req_name values also displaying inother  input fields in next page how can i do that one

Comment: `href="data.php?requirement_number=<?php echo $row['Requirement_Number'];?>&req_name=<?php echo $row['Req_name'];?>">` as you can see here I used & to add multiple variables, you can add as much variables as you want by splitting them with &

Comment: after getting values to the input field in next i click submit button in the next page shows data inserted successfully and one button is there "add new" when i click "add new" button it going to input field page but the values are not getting how can i do that

Comment: after getting values from previous page i click submit button and going to next page and shows inserted succesfully and there is one button add new when i click the button going to input field "below form" but values not getting <form class="form-inline" action="datasubmit.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" onkeypress="return noenter()"name="Requirement_Number" value='<?php echo $row['requimentnumber'];?>'>                        <input type="date" onkeypress="return noenter()" id="Req_Date" name="Req_Date" value='<?php echo $reqdate;?>'/>  <input type = "submit" name="submit">